I need multiple custom game objects to stick to a parent object
A bit of a newb to Unity & game development. I have built a very basic lunar lander ship and made some RCS thrusters out of cubes and cylinders to attach to the fuselage of the ship. However, whenever I apply main thrust, the ship moves, but the RCS thrusters remain in their original location. Is there a known method for having multiple "child" game objects "stick" to a parent gameobject?

Say you have two GameObjects p and c. You can make c a child of p by dragging c into p in the Hierarchy panel. See the documentation.
This is a basic fundamental of the Unity Editor. If you did not know how to do this already, you should take some time to learn how to use the Editor. Try reading the documentation and going through tutorials. Also, basic questions like this can generally be answered with a simple web search.
Note: If a child has a Rigidbody, it will move independently of its parent unless you add a Joint or Constraint (as DMGregory noted, Joints are better for Rigidbodies). If you want the children to be fixed in place relative to the parent, it's probably better not to give them a Rigidbody component unless you have a specific need for it.
If you wanted the thrusters to be able to apply forces to the lander, one thing you can do instead is use Rigidbody.AddForceAtPosition() to apply the force directly to the lander's Rigidbody.

Ahhhh...so, it sounds like I did it right by adding the thruster to the main lander object in the hierarchy pane. But because I added a Rigidbody component to each thruster, they now track as separate gameobjects. Is that a proper interpretation?

@Skittles If a thruster has a Rigidbody, it will move independently of its parent (the lander). There are some exceptions - if the thruster has a Constraint component, if any of the position "Constraints" in the Rigidbody component are selected (note these are settings in the Rigidbody, not separate components), or if the thruster's Rigidbody has "is kinematic" checked. Generally I would recommend not putting Rigidbodies on the thrusters (they can still have colliders), but it will depend on your specific goals.

I updated the answer with a note about using Rigidbody.AddForceAtPosition().

@Kevin - My desired result is that I would like to apply force at the thruster nozzle and have it effect the parent by imposing a rotation relative to the axis of the thruster's position on the fuselage. So, is it safe to assume that the AddForceAtPosition will do what it sounds like? Adding force at the thruster position relative to the parent?

@Skittles Yep. As noted in the documentation, "As a result this will apply a torque and force on the object."

I'm using this for applying the RCS thrust force on the Y-axis;
thrusterRb.AddForceAtPosition(new Vector3(0f, thrust * Time.deltaTime, 0f), transform.localPosition, ForceMode.Acceleration);

Do not multiply an acceleration by deltaTime. You want the units to be m/s² not m/s. The physics engine will handle integrating it over a physics time step. As stated in the docs, AddForceAtPosition takes the force and position in world space, not local space. You can also apply this directly to the parent body without the thruster having its own, like so: landerBody.AddForceAtPosition(transform.up * acceleration, transform.position, ForceMode.Acceleration)

@DMGregory - This is OUTSTANDING educational help! I will try these suggestions and see how they play out. Thank you ever so much!
